# Sparse matrix multiplication in R: error in Ubuntu, flawless in Windows

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix

The CRAN Matrix package can be used to multiply a column vector by its transpose:

```r
product <- Matrix::t(dtm.t) %*% dtm.t
```

where `dtm.t` is a column vector created from a Document Term Matrix.

When I run the above line in an Ubuntu installation (versions 6.4 and above), it throws the error message:

> Error in `Matrix::t(dtm.t) %*% dtm.t` :
> not-yet-implemented method for `<dgRMatrix> %*% <dgCMatrix>`

which basically means that the multiplication isn't implemented for sparse matrices. This is strange, because objects of class `dgRMatrix` and `dgCMatrix` are both defined in the `Matrix` package.

Interestingly, the line executes without any errors when I run it on a Windows 11 installation.

Has anyone else observed this error? What might be causing it?

Comment: can we have some more information please? (1) what are the results of `sessionInfo()` from both machines? Any chance you can make a [mcve]?  I'm not sure how you ended up with a `dgRMatrix` ...

Comment: "... which basically means that the multiplication isn't implemented for sparse matrices" is not right. The product of `dgRMatrix` and `dgCMatrix` (two specific classes of sparse matrices) is not implemented. `<dgCMatrix> %*% <dgCMatrix>` and other pairings (see `showMethods("%*%")`) _are_ implemented. `?\`RsparseMatrix-class\`` does warn that row-oriented storage has minimal support. Admittedly, that help page isn't especially easy to find.

Comment: If you somehow obtain a `dgRMatrix`, then coerce to `dgCMatrix` via `dgTMatrix` with `as(as(<dgRMatrix>, "TsparseMatrix"), "CsparseMatrix")`, before trying to compute things. (I guess the direct coercion isn't implemented yet.) With a `dgCMatrix` `x`, you can do `t(x) %*% x` or (more efficiently) `crossprod(x)`.

Comment: @BenBolker I'm guessing you imputed the error message from the two classes that the OP mentioned, but this specific error message seems implausible given that `t` doesn't change storage format. AFAICT, `t(<dg[CRT]Matrix>)` is always a `dg[CRT]Matrix`. I agree that we need more information...

Comment: Thanks for your responses.

I face this error when I use either the method FitLdaModel, or FitCtmModel (part of the package textmineR). If I keep calc_coherence TRUE, the subroutine proceeds to calculate the mean coherence of model (the relevant code is here: https://rdrr.io/cran/textmineR/src/R/evaluation_metrics.R).

1/2

Comment: The part where the code gets stuck when I run it on Ubuntu versions 6.4 and above (running Spark 3.0.1 and above) is:

count.mat <- Matrix::t(dtm.t) %*% dtm.t

where dtm is a sparse matrix of type dgCMatrix (as defined in the Matrix package itself).

I repeat: this problem disappears the moment I run the exact same code on a Windows 11 installation.

The dataset is an ordinary text corpus.

2/2

Comment: @arkobose We can't answer without a minimal reproducible example. You need to share code and data that reproduce the behaviour that you are reporting, _and_ you need to share the output of `sessionInfo()` on both of your machines, as requested by @BenBolker.

Comment: @arkobose I would expect `t(x) %*% x` to throw an error if `x` were a `dgRMatrix`, but not otherwise.

Comment: @MikaelJagan yes, x in this case is indeed a dgRMatrix. But the multiplication faces no issues on a Windows system.

I fixed the problem using a somewhat inefficient hack: by typecasting x using as.matrix(x), and then using t(x) %*% x.